# Title multi-page articles such that users can search Google for all the pages of the article, or any single page unambiguously

Tags: google-search, blogger

I am using a custom .com domain with Blogger so my site appears as regular web site. I have not modified the search code.

Some of larger articles will be divided into multiple chapters. I don't wish to insert the standard "Part 1", "Part 2", "Part 3" into the title. I wish to use a simple notation system for each article and chapter within the title.

I am having problems coming up with a scheme that will allow the user to search for all chapters within an article or just one chapter.

#### Example 1

5 denotes the article number and the second digit denotes the chapter. If the user searches for 5p it produces no results whereas I want them to find all the parts. Searching for individual chapters such as 5p1 works.

- 5p1
- 5p2
- 5p3

#### Example 2

- 5p-1
- 5p-2
- 5p-3

If user searches for 5p- it returns all of the articles. If the user searches for 5p-1 or 5p-3 it shows 5p-1 and 5p-3. If the user searches for 5p-2 it shows all three chapters.

I've tried various combinations in the title and have read several articles about Google ignoring punctuation and other special characters.

How can I title the articles so that they are searchable like I want?

Comment: Users aren't going to search like that unless you tell them to do so, or  link to the search results for those searches.   Why is this search feature important to you?